# Christoffel symbol in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I'm working through this problem in Problem Book in Relativity and Gravitation. The book shows the full solution. I'm trying to understand it all.

"For a 2-dimensional flat, Euclidean space described by polar coordinates $r$, $\theta$, assume that geodesics are the usual straight lines. Find the connection coefficients $\Gamma^\alpha _{\beta \gamma}$ using your knowledge of these geodesics, and the geodesic equation"

$$
\frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2} + \frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds}\Gamma^\mu _{\alpha \beta} = 0
$$

Using the equation of a line in polar coordinates, this can be parameterized in terms of $\theta$.

$$
R_{0} = r\cos(\theta - a) 
$$

$$
\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\theta^2} - 2\ tan(\theta - a)\ \frac{dx^\mu}{d\theta} + \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\theta}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\theta}\Gamma^\mu _{\alpha \beta} = 0
$$

Then the text states to "consider the point $\theta = a$" where we get:

$$
\Gamma^\theta _{\theta \theta} = 0
$$

$$
\Gamma^r_{\theta \theta} = -r
$$

But then the text states "Since $a$ and $R_0$ are arbitrary (this) is true in general."

This is what I don't understand. The point $\theta$ = $a$ refers to a very specific point on the line: the point closest to the origin. So we have found that $\Gamma^\theta _{\theta \theta} = 0$ and $\Gamma^r_{\theta \theta} = -r$ at the point closest to the origin. How does that generalize to all other points? For any point on a line one could to a change of coordinates so that that point was closest to the origin, but then the derived Christoffel symbol would be be for a different coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what they're talking about. You compute the Christoffel symbols from the parametrization. Indeed, $\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta}=0$. This has nothing to do with any curve in the surface.

**EDIT**: Now that I correctly conjectured what must have been in the text, there's no problem with what is written. You are told to assume that every line in the plane is a geodesic. Given any value $(r_0,\theta_0)$, choose $R_0 = r_0$ and $a=\theta_0$, and you've deduced what the author claims. But this tells you the values of the Christoffel symbols at an arbitrary point of the plane.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I expanded my question to include how parameterization was used. The text does use a point on the line to make the step from the parameterization to the result. Maybe you can clarify what they are trying to express?

Comment: I'm talking about the polar coordinate parametrization. You just calculate the Christoffel symbols. Is the author perhaps trying to deduce the Christoffel symbols *knowing* that the geodesics are lines? This is the trouble with just pulling things out of books without full context.

Comment: That is exactly it. I've now edited the question to include the problem posed in the text, pretty much word for word. It probably would have been better to do that in the first place.

Comment: To clarify my understanding of the recent edit to the answer: The Christoffel symbol is a property of the coordinate system, not any particular curve. So for an arbitrary point, I could use any curve to deduce the Christoffel symbol. In this case, for an arbitrary point I choose the geodesic for which the arbitrary point is the point on the geodesic closest to the origin. I use that to derive the result given. Is that thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This exercise is, however, backwards from the situation in which one ordinarily finds oneself. Ordinarily, one is given the metric (or an embedding of our surface) in some local coordinates. One computes the Christoffel symbols and then wants to use that system of ODEs to *find* the geodesics. Try it for polar coordinates in the plane, knowing those Christoffel symbols and also $\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta} = \Gamma^\theta_{\theta r} = 1/r$, all others $0$. (Amusingly, this is actually an exercise in my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.)